# LVM not showing LV although it's in use

Tags: lvm

I have a machine with a RAID-1 (sda) hosting Debian 10 and a RAID-5 being used for storage (sdb), both using independent PGs. Recently the RAID-5 was corrupted, so I recreated it and set up the LVM again:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
vgcreate "server-h01-space" /dev/sdb1
lvcreate -n "storage" -L 20.5T server-h01-space
```

During setup `pvcreate` and `vgcreate` reported an existing XFS signature and offered to wipe it. I declined in the hope that the filesystem could be recovered. However, `lvcreate` failed as it could not find a volume group. I rebooted the machine and ran the commands again, this time wiping the XFS signature. After that I set up the filesystem on `/dev/mapper/server--h01--space-storage` and mounted it.

However, while everything seems to have worked fine, all LVM commands only show what has been created on sda. I.e. the *display commands report

```
# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               server-h01
  PV Size               134.75 GiB / not usable 0
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              34497
  Free PE               7873
  Allocated PE          26624
  PV UUID               aaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeee-ffff-ggggg

# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               server-h01
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  23
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               4
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               134.75 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              34497
  Alloc PE / Size       26624 / 104.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       7873 / 30.75 GiB
  VG UUID               11111-2222-3333-4444-5555-6666-7777-88888

# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/server-h01/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                server-h01
  LV UUID                ***
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time Microknoppix, 2019-10-09 10:48:26 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                25.00 GiB
  Current LE             6400
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/server-h01/tmp
  LV Name                tmp
  VG Name                server-h01
  LV UUID                ***
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time Microknoppix, 2019-10-09 10:48:37 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                7.00 GiB
  Current LE             1792
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/server-h01/var
  LV Name                var
  VG Name                server-h01
  LV UUID                ***
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time Microknoppix, 2019-10-09 10:48:53 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                63.00 GiB
  Current LE             1280
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/server-h01/log
  LV Name                log
  VG Name                server-h01
  LV UUID                ***
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time server-h01, 2019-10-13 21:40:41 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                9.00 GiB
  Current LE             2304
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:6
```

This is contradicted by the output of `mount`

```
# mount|grep -e "^\/dev"
/dev/mapper/server--h01-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/server--h01-tmp on /tmp type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,grpquota)
/dev/mapper/server--h01-var on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,grpquota)
/dev/mapper/server--h01-log on /var/log type xfs (rw,noexec,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/server--h01--space-storage on /storage type xfs (rw,noexec,relatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,grpquota)
```

I am afraid that the LVM is not persistent and will be lost with the next reboot. Unfortunately I discovered the issue only after /storage was populated with several TB of data.

Any ideas why `mount` does not agree with `pvdisplay`?

Edit: Output of *scan commands as requested:

```
# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda2   VG server-h01      lvm2 [134.75 GiB / 30.75 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [134.75 GiB] / in use: 1 [134.75 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "server-h01" using metadata type lvm2

# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/server-h01/root' [25.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/server-h01/tmp' [7.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/server-h01/var' [63.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/server-h01/log' [9.00 GiB] inherit
```

Edit: These are the relevant logs from /etc/lvm/archive

```
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.03.02(2) (2018-12-18): Sun May 14 15:56:19 2023

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *before* executing 'vgcreate server-h01-space /dev/sdb1'"

creation_host = "server-h01"    # Linux server-h01 4.19.0-24-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.282-1 (2023-04-29) x86_6
4
creation_time = 1684072579      # Sun May 14 15:56:19 2023

server-h01-space {
        id = "***"
        seqno = 0
        format = "lvm2"                 # informational
        status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
        flags = []
        extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
        max_lv = 0
        max_pv = 0
        metadata_copies = 0

        physical_volumes {

                pv0 {
                        id = "***"
                        device = "/dev/sdb1"    # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 58599665664  # 27.2876 Terabytes
                        pe_start = 2048
                        pe_count = 7153279      # 27.2876 Terabytes
                }
        }


}


# Generated by LVM2 version 2.03.02(2) (2018-12-18): Sun May 14 15:56:43 2023

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *before* executing 'lvcreate -n server -L 20.5T server-h01-space'"

creation_host = "server-h01"    # Linux server-h01 4.19.0-24-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.282-1 (2023-04-29) x86_6
4
creation_time = 1684072603      # Sun May 14 15:56:43 2023

server-h01-space {
        id = "***"
        seqno = 1
        format = "lvm2"                 # informational
        status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
        flags = []
        extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
        max_lv = 0
        max_pv = 0
        metadata_copies = 0

        physical_volumes {

                pv0 {
                        id = "***"
                        device = "/dev/sdb1"    # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 58599665664  # 27.2876 Terabytes
                        pe_start = 2048
                        pe_count = 7153279      # 27.2876 Terabytes
                }
        }


}
```

Comment: Please don't use R5, it's dangerous.

Comment: Please show the output of `pvscan`, `vgscan`, `lvscan`.

Comment: Please run `pvscan --cache /dev/sdb1`

Comment: The output of ```pvscan --cache /dev/sdb1```` is empty

Comment: does `sdb` even show up in `fdisk -l`?

Comment: It does, as does ```/dev/mapper/server--h01--space-storage```. FYI, /dev/sdb is GPT and sdb1 was created with ```parted```

Comment: is this of any use?  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/limiting-lvm-device-visibility-and-usage_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes#adding-devices-to-the-system-devices-file_the-lvm-devices-file